# Handling the upgrade of a request client-side

Tags: go, websocket, server, client, gorilla

I'm probably being stupid here, but I am upgrading a HTML Request to a WS, with Gorilla Mux, and can't seem to figure out how to access the WebSocket on the Webpage after upgrade,

```go
func loadSecureThing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if helpers.IsLocalRequest(r) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "secure-login-thing.html")
        c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Upgrade error: Please contact server admin.")
            return
        }
         //Authentication stuff
        defer c.Close()
```

I've looked up how to handle upgrade but I see them opening a new WS connection with

```js
const wss = new WebSocket('wss://route');

socket.onopen = function (event) {
    document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
        //send auth stuff with JWT
    })
}
```

This creates a new WSS, when we already have one that's been upgraded, so im confused how I would access this upgraded request on the client side.

I expected to be able to send messages through this WSS connection from the server, after the initial request has been upgraded on the client side,

Thank you friends :)

Comment: "when we already have one that's been upgraded" - but do you? You can't just upgrade any request (it needs to contain an `upgrade` header; I'd expect your code to output "Upgrade error" if you try it). You need to accept websocket requests on a dedicated route (see [this demo](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/main/examples/chat/main.go#L34)).

Comment: Use variable `wss` to access the upgraded connection on the client.  The client's WebSocket type manages the handshake with the server for you. The server application send messages immediately after a successful return from upgrader.Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of a Websocket is initiated by the client by a special upgrade request. A server cannot simply upgrade an arbitrary request to Websocket and then return this back to the client, instead only explicit requests for a Websocket can be upgraded. It is also not possible to serve a normal HTTP response before upgrading, instead the only possible response is either a successful upgrade or a failure.